# Showing a set is closed under complement

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu_1)$ and $(Y,\mathcal{B},\mu_2)$ be two $\sigma$-finite measure space. Let $\mu$ be the product measure of $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$. For any set $E\subset X \times Y$, and $x\in X$, define $E_x=\{y\in Y: (x,y)\in E\}$.

Then we can define a function $g$ on $X$ by $g(x)= \mu_2(E_x)$.

Let $\mathcal{S}=\{E\subset X\times Y: g\  \text{is $\mathcal{A}$-measurable}\ \text{and} \int_X g \,d\mu_1=\mu(E)\}$.

How to show that this $\mathcal{S}$ is closed under complement.
i.e. How to show that if $E\in \mathcal{S}$, then $E^c\in \mathcal{S}$?

I got stuck with showing function $h(x):=\mu_2(E^c_x)$ is $\mathcal{A}$-measurable.